# How can I limit the resize scale of a div so it cant get bigger than the parent div

Tags: javascript

So I got a resizable Div which lays in the parent Div.
The Problem is, I can resize the childDiv much larger than the parentDiv.
How can i limit the resizing?

```css
.borderbox {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.movebox {
  height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    display:flex;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderbox">
  <div class="movebox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the parent to `position: relative;` and then apply a `max-width` and `max-height` of `100%` to your child element.

```css
.borderbox {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.movebox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  display:flex;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderbox">
  <div class="movebox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I understand. But if I give the parent position:relative, I cant move my div anymore. I put the javascript of the movement in my question...

Comment: Here is my code with JS: https://codepen.io/nicokampf/pen/poePKWM

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `position: absolute;` in class `movebox`

Demo:

```css
.borderbox {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.movebox {
  height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    display:flex;
    background-color: orange;
    max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="borderbox">
  <div class="movebox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please may you add a [mcve] to the answer as well as the fiddle link? Fiddle links tend to "rot".

Comment: (You can keep the fiddle link if you like, it’s just good to show a demo in the answer too)